# can a function reference itself in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, this

Suppose we define a function that simply increments its input by some stored value `dd`:

```
var obj={}
obj.dd=1
obj.f=function(x){
    return x+this.dd
}
```

Alternatively you could create a closure for `dd` as follows but this would create a static increment as opposed to one that could be altered later:

```
var dd=1
var f=function(x){
    return x+dd
}
```

We could alternatively store `dd` in the function itself:

```
var obj={}
obj.f=function(x){
    return x+this.f.dd
}
obj.f.dd=1
```

I am curious as to whether it is possible for a function to retrieve a variable attached to itself without going through a parent object, something like a `self` keyword that would refer to the function itself and would allow the following:

```
var f=function(x){
    return x+self.dd
}
f.dd=1
```

I know it is unnecessary to do such a thing but I think it would be cool if you could.

Comment: Other answers already cover whether this is technically feasible or not. However, I would highly recommend keeping it simple and using regular features to do the same thing (this / closures). Not only will it be more familiar for most people but mutating function attributes will disable many compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give function literals a name:

```
var f = function me(x) {
    return x + me.dd;
};

f.dd = 1;
```

This doesn’t work properly in older versions of IE/JScript, though, as `me` and `f` don’t reference the same object. The (deprecated and not usable in strict mode) alternative is `arguments.callee`:

```
var f = function(x) {
    return x + arguments.callee.dd;
};

f.dd = 1;
```

Also, your note about the closure isn’t quite right; it can be altered later, even through another function:

```
var dd = 1;
var f = function(x) {
    return x + dd;
};

var setdd = function(_dd) {
    dd = _dd;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I take it that there is simply no way to create an anonymous function that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I have question on stackover etiquette. I realize now that fumbled my question and I meant to ask if such a behavior is possible in an anonymous function. Should I post a new question or edit the existing one?

Comment: @gloo: You can edit your question. Anyways, yes, you can, using `arguments.callee`; but what’s the point of an “anonymous function”? You can use a named function literal anywhere you can use an anonymous function literal. The *only* caveat is IE 8-, and `argument.callee` has worked since IE3 or something, so no worries there.

Comment: I agree there is no reason to do this. I was just curious if it were possible. I will definitely check out `argument.callee`.

Answer (score 2):

A function is an object.  If you reference the var holding the function:

```
var f = function (x) {
    return x + f.dd
};

f.dd = 1;

alert(f(1));
```

result: `2`

If the function is named, you can do the same:

```
function foo(x) {
    return x + foo.dd;
}

foo.dd = 1;
alert(foo(1));
```

result: `2`